# Reversing Words Functionally in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I can reverse every word in a string functionally without using a loop, but when I try to reverse EVERY OTHER WORD. I run into problems. I can do it with a loop but not functionally. What am I not seeing here?

Functionally (every word):

```
import UIKit

let input = "This is a sample sentence"

func reverseWords(input: String) -> String {
    let parts = input.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let reversed = parts.map { String($0.reversed()) }
    return reversed.joined(separator: " ")
}

reverseWords(input: input)
```

With loop (EVERY OTHER WORD):

```
var sampleSentence = "This is a sample sentence"

func reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: String) -> String {
    let allWords = sampleSentence.components(separatedBy:" ")
    var newSentence = ""

    for index in 0...allWords.count - 1 {
        let word = allWords[index]
        if newSentence != "" {
            newSentence += " "
        }

        if index % 2 == 1 {
            let reverseWord = String(word.reversed())
            newSentence += reverseWord
        } else {
            newSentence += word
        }
    }
    return newSentence
}
reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: sampleSentence)
```

Comment: I recommend you add a sample input with an expected output. At least personally, for me, your question is a bit unclear but an example of what you want to achieve will help me greatly. Adding the current output will help too.

Comment: "This is a sample sentence" will look like this: "This si a elpmas sentence" with every other word reversed.

Comment: Two things. First, what *is* the output (not what are you expecting, what is your code yielding)? Second, have you put in breakpoints and actually looked at the output you are building?

Comment: He posted the imperative code for his goal, and is asking for help with an equivalent functional version. See my answer.

Comment: Andy Ibanez and dfd ... The code posted above outputs properly. I am simply trying to find a way to get every other word reversed using functional programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a slight modification of your `reverseWords` you can reverse every other word.  Use `enumerated()` to combine a word with its position, and then use that to reverse odd words:

```
let input = "one two three four five"

func reverseOddWords(input: String) -> String {
    let parts = input.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let reversed = parts.enumerated().map { $0 % 2 == 0 ? String($1.reversed()) : $1 }
    return reversed.joined(separator: " ")
}

print(reverseOddWords(input: input))
```

> > ```
> > eno two eerht four evif
> > ```

---

Or you could pattern your function after Swift's `sort` and pass the `filter` closure to the `reverseWords` function:

```
let input = "one two three four five"

func reverseWords(_ input: String, using filter: ((Int) -> Bool) = { _ in true }) -> String {
    let parts = input.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let reversed = parts.enumerated().map { filter($0) ? String($1.reversed()) : $1 }
    return reversed.joined(separator: " ")
}

// default behavior is to reverse all words
print(reverseWords("one two three four five"))
```

> > ```
> > eno owt eerht ruof evif
> > ```

```
print(reverseWords("one two three four five", using: { $0 % 2 == 1 }))
```

> > ```
> > one owt three ruof five
> > ```

```
print(reverseWords("one two three four five", using: { [0, 3, 4].contains($0) }))
```

> > ```
> > eno two three ruof evif
> > ```

```
let everyThirdWord = { $0 % 3 == 0 }

print(reverseWords("one two three four five", using: everyThirdWord))
```

> > ```
> > eno two three ruof five
> > ```

Comment: Oh man! You created a higher order function for reversing certain words? You get extra credit for that, for sure. (voted.) Now you could feed in the Fibonacci sequence as a filter if you wanted to!

Answer (score 2):

Use `stride()` to generate a sequence of indexes of every other word.

Then use `forEach()` to select each index in the stride array and use it to mutate the word at that index to reverse it.

```
import UIKit

let string = "Now is the time for all good programmers to babble incoherently"

var words = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

stride(from: 0, to: words.count, by: 2)
.forEach { words[$0] = String(words[$0].reversed()) }


let newString = words.joined(separator: " ")

print(newString)
```

The output string is:

```
"woN is eht time rof all doog programmers ot babble yltnerehocni"
```

Comment: Are you REALLY that lazy? See if you can convert it to a function yourself.